# How to insert array to db using create Laravel method?

Tags: laravel, database

There is a controller method:

```
public function addEducation(AddPatientEducationRequest $request) {

    dd($request->all());

    $state = UserEducation::create($request->validated());
}
```

The dd() returns me an array that I need to insert into db:

```
array:1 [ // app\Http\Controllers\Api\PatientController.php:99
  "education" => array:1 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "patient_id" => 1
      "education_id" => 2
      "diplom" => "ZV 800"
      "start_date" => "2021-10-30"
      "end_date" => "2022-10-30"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I tried this way using loop:

`foreach($request->education as $value) { UserEducation::create($value); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content looks like this:

```
[
    'education' => [
        //some fields
    ]
]
```

So, you can reach your record like this:

```
myArray['education'][0]
```

, hence your script should be

```
foreach($request['education'] as $value) {
    UserEducation::create($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `education` multidimensional array  matches database columns then you can use the insert method like below

```
UserEducation::insert($request->education)
```

Ref :[Insert Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements)